# Android Ksoap how to set maximum string content length quota

Tags: android, wcf, ksoap2

When I try to call my WCF web service by parsing large string value it gives me this error

SoapFault - faultcode: 'a:DeserializationFailed' faultstring: 'The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'GetLandmarks'. The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data.

This quota may be increased by changing the MaxStringContentLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader. Line 1, position 9593.' faultactor: 'null' detail: null

I found that in WCF I can increase this maxStringContentLength but I couldn't find any way to increase this value from ksoap2. Can any one help me please.

Answer (score 0):

You must increase this value in WCF on service side - it is WCF settings and your exception directly says that error happened in request = when your Android client send a message to your WCF service.